# Ruby on Rails search 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, models

Right... I've spent 3 days trying to do this myself to no a vale.

I have 2 models called Film and Screenings. Screenings belongs_to Film, Film has_many Screenings.

The Film has certain attributes(:title, :date_of_release, :description, :genre).

The Screening has the attributes(:start_time, :date_being_screened, :film_id(foreign key of Film)).

What I am trying to do is create a Search against both of these models.
I want to do something like this...

@films = Film.advanced_search(params[:genre], params[:title], params[:start_time], params[:date_showing])

And then in the Film model...

```
def self.advanced_search(genre, title, start_time, date)
    search_string = "%" + title + "%"

    self.find(:all, :conditions => ["title LIKE ? OR genre = ? OR start_time LIKE ? OR date_showing = ?", title, genre, start_time, date], order: 'title')
    end
end
```

I don't think this could ever work quite like this, but I'm hoping my explanation is detailed enough for anyone to understand what im TRYING to do?? :-/

Thanks for any help guys

Comment: Could you explain what's the result you want in plain text instead of code?

Comment: Sorry... I'd like the result to be a collection of films, that meet the criteria of the :conditions. I can get it it work for searching inside one model but not two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extract the search capability into a separate (non-ActiveRecord) class, such as `AdvancedSearch` as it doesn't neatly fit into either the `Film` or `Screening` class.

Rather than writing a complex SQL query, you could just search the films, then the screenings, and combine the results, for example:

```
class AdvancedSearch
  def self.search
    film_matches = Film.advanced_search(...) # return an Array of Film objects
    screening_matches = Screening.advanced_search(...) # return an Array of Screening objects

    # combine the results
    results = film_matches + screening_matches.map(&:film)

    results.uniq # may be necessary to remove duplicates
  end
end
```

Update

Let's say your advanced search form has two fields - Genre and Location. So when you submit the form, the params sent are:

```
{ :genre => 'Comedy', :location => 'London' }
```

Your controller would then something like:

```
def advanced_search(params)
  film_matches = Film.advanced_search(:genre => params[:genre])
  screening_matches = Screening.advanced_search(:location => params[:location])

  # remaining code as above 
end
```

i.e. you're splitting the params, sending each to a different model to run a search, and then combining the results.

This is essentially an OR match - it would return films that match the genre or are being screened at that specified venue. (If you wanted and AND match you would need to the work out the array intersection).

Comment: That looks like just the thing! I will get back to you soon with an up date... thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: When you say seperate (non ActiveRecord), do you mean a new controller and model called advanced_search? Sorry for being dumb :-/

Comment: No, you don't need a controller or model. The concept is known as a service object. See http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: I'm so confused... sorry, where would this new advancedsearch class be placed?

Comment: Some people would put it in `/lib` but since it's closely related to your domain logic I would keep it in `/app/models`. (I may have confused you earlier when I said you don't need a model - I meant you don't need an ActiveRecord model).

Comment: I am a complete noob, in my app/model folder, I have the models film, screening etc... so are you sayin i need to create a new model called AdvancedSearch and have the self. action placed inside that model? :-/

Comment: Correct. And you then call that from your controller.

Comment: arggghhhh... just seen your message again. SO I do need to create a model for it call AdvancedSearch... i thought that earlier haha... No problems for the confusion, I really appreciate your responses.

Comment: So am I calling it from an AdvancedSearch controller or the Film controller? arrgghhh... sorry mate. I'm just think about your previous comment about not needin a model or controller. I need a model but do i need a controller also? I cant see how else it would work :-/

Comment: Either will work. Without knowing how your app is structured is hard to say where it should go. Get it working then refactor.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks again for all your help. I've managed to get it 'sort of working' bu then broke again :-/  Can you let me know how you intende me to call the AdvancedSearch from the films controller? I', struggling with how and where I am passing all the params etc?

Comment: ... and do i need to create a realtionship between my new AdvancedSearch model with Film and Screening

Comment: I've updated my answer. You don't to create any new ActiveRecord relationship.

Comment: Top man! Thanks for your patience! Ill let you know when its working!!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write something but this cast says all http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form

Almost the same case as yours.

Comment: Thanks for the link buts not quite what I want... the code and suggestion offer by Andy Waite seems to be the exact kind of functionality I need.... I just cant figure out where I'm supposed to include the AdvancedSearch class he's provided... any ideas?